# Matplotlib asks username when imported

Tags: python

I am trying to fix this but I can't understand why it asks me for a 'username' and 'user id'.

```
What user name
username: 

What is the user id
Enter user id:
```

Can anyone run it without problems?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5

mMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
wMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.5

plt.bar(ind, mMeans, width)
plt.bar(ind, wMeans, width, bottom=mMeans)
plt.show()
```

This is what appears when I abort the run (Ctrl + c):

```
$ python stack.py 

    What username
    username:
```

Here is where I stopped the command.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
          File "stack.py", line 5, in <module>
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

[image: What appears including using IDLE]

```
What user name

username: ^CTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "stack.py", line 4, in 

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt #.pyplot as plt

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 36, in 

    from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 70, in 

    from PIL import Image

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 107, in 
    import builtins

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/builtins/__init__.py", line 8, in 

    from future.builtins import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/builtins/__init__.py", line 10, in 

    from future.builtins.iterators import (filter, map, zip)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/builtins/iterators.py", line 43, in 

    from future.types import newrange as range

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/types/__init__.py", line 243, in 

    from .newrange import newrange

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/types/newrange.py", line 25, in 

    from future.backports.misc import count   # with step parameter on Py2.6
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/backports/__init__.py", line 17, in 

    from .misc import (ceil,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/backports/misc.py", line 17, in 

    import subprocess

  File "/home/flira/Downloads/subprocess.py", line 6, in 

    username = str(raw_input('username: '))

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: I can run the 2nd block of code if I change `menMeans` and `womenMeans` to `mMeans` and `hMeans`. I'm not sure why `pandas` is involved according to you....

Comment: when you run the above script it asks for username?

Comment: I don't see any pandas import here but someone sure meddled with source code of your modules as the prompt questions are grammatically incorrect :)

Comment: Ok, there are mistakes in the posted code, now fixed, but it still ask me for username. I have no idea why

Comment: What line results in the requests for an username ? Is is really one of the import statements ? Can you try a simple `print` statement

Comment: I included a  - print 'ok' - after each line. It passes the first (import numpy as np). It ask me for username when importing matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: The problem occurs when importing matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: @Jaco I complemented the question in order to give you more information.

Comment: (Note: there is no need to add the answer to the question, nor add a [solved] device to the title - the acceptance and the answer below is fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a faulty/personal version of `subprocess` in your `PYTHONPATH`.

```
username = str(raw_input('username: '))
```

does not exist in any python distribution of `subprocess.py` I'm familiar with. Delete/rename that file, or better yet, remove

```
/home/flira/Downloads/
```

from your `PYTHONPATH`. The way to install any library is through `apt-get`, not by downloading it manually (if you're not sure of what you're doing).

**Further investigation**

I now noticed your terminal screenshot - you're running from Downloads, hence the file is in you path. Get rid of it.

Comment: Now I'm wondering how you got your configuration setup like that. Where did you download subprocess from? And why the heck did Downloads get to your path? One of the weirdest issues ever.

Comment: I don't use to install libraries downloading the file, always apt-get. I will check and return.

Comment: @F.Lira Good luck. I noticed you're running from Downloads - that's why it's in your PYTHONPATH - remove or rename the file.

Comment: I removed the subprocess.py* files.